# Regex string should contain Double quotes and comma seperated numbers only

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have following string

```
"56565665,5656565,5656556"
```

I want to just check that the **string must only contain Double quotes, Comma and numbers.**

for that I have tried creating a regex  `^"\d+\,` but it only selects first string.

I am new to regex completely.

Comment: First you need to think of valid and invalid matches. Regexp will depend completely on that. For example, good matches: `"12"`, `"1"`, `"1,2"`, `"123,123"`, `"1,1,1,1"`. Bad matches: `","`, `"12,"`, `"1,2,"`, `"s2"`, `12,12` `",1"` and so on.

Comment: Some handy testcases  would be `""`, `1"5,87"`, `"56,,76"`, `"8766,87,"`. I would use `@"\A""[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*""\z"`

Comment: Also, what about an empty string? Regexes are very fragile and only "work" when a complete set of requirements is known beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^"[\d,]+"$`

See it here on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oP0sD0/2)

In C# it would look like this due to escaping chars

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions
...
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@"""56565665,5656565,5656556""", @"^""[\d,]+""$"));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@"""56565665,5656565;5656556""", @"^""[\d,]+""$"));
```

---

Update due to question in comments about how to use it with a variable:

```
var str = @"""56565665,5656565,5656556""";
// var str = "\"56565665,5656565,5656556\""; <- Alternative way of escaping "  

Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^""[\d,]+""$"))
```

Comment: and how do I use this? 
`var pattern = "^"[\d,]+"$"; // this line gives error

Comment: `var pattern = @"^""[\d,]+""$";`

Comment: Just a note: `\d` matches `[0-9]`, Hindi, Arabic and what-not digits in .NET. To only match 0-9 with `\d`, compile the regex with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag.

Comment: @DAXaholic Thanks for the update. but I can not hard code it the way you did right? when I use `var str = "56565665,5656565,5656556"  Regex.IsMatch(@"" + str + "",@"^""[\d,]+""$");`
It returns false only. :(

Comment: I did another update. In case you just have 56565665,5656565,5656556 , i.e. no " around the string, then you can add them via @"""" to the beginning / ending of the string but I don't get the point why you want to do that because then you could simply adjust the regex so that it does not require " around the string.

Comment: counter example: `","`: just comma, no numbers

Comment: Well according to the question only numbers, commas and double quotes are allowed but there is nothing about what's required. But I agree that he probably wants to avoid your case

Comment: you saved my day! Thanks  @Wiktor Stribiżew for your valuable comments

Answer (score 1):

Try this , hope this will work 
"^[0-9,]+$"

Answer (score 1):

You can try the pattern below:

```
 ^"[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*"$
```

or even

```
 \A"[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*"\z //  Wiktor Stribiżew's idea, see his comment below
```

E.g.

```
 string source = @"""123,456,789""";
 string pattern = @"\A""[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*""\z";

 bool result = Regex.IsMatch(source, pattern);
```

Tests:

```
 "123"       - true  // just a number
 "123,456"   - true  // two numbers separated by comma
 "1,2,3,4"   - true  // four numbers separated by comma 
 ","         - false // just a comma, no numbers
 ",123"      - false // leading comma
 "123,"      - false // trailing comma
 "123,,456"  - false // double comma
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer with explaination!

Comment: Dima, this is my suggestion. I just would use the `\A` and `\z` anchors to make sure my string does not end with an LF. Your regex allows `"12,23\n"`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: Thank you! Nice catch of the subtle error; I've edited the anser.

Comment: Well, that is no error, just a slight correction. Also, Exlicit Capture flag would be handy since you are using a capturing group but are not using the captured value anywhere.